# mdadm - Drive has incorrect type after reboot

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a raid 6 setup with six drives using mdadm. I noticed I had a failed drive (b) that was not responding at all. Making sure all drives are properly connected I stopped the raid, unmounted and shutdown my computer. When starting it back up mdadm where unable to recreate the array. The failed drive (b) where back and working, even detected by mdadm, however two of the other drives (d & f) were not picked up by mdadm despite both functioning beforehand. They now show up as "Micsrosoft reserved". Various status command output,

#### Output: `fdisk -l /dev/sda /dev/sdd`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9ac08c50

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT


Disk /dev/sdd: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D599B9D7-1648-11E7-9C1F-74D02B2AF0E1

Device     Start    End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1     34 262177  262144  128M Microsoft reserved
```

#### Output: `mdadm -E /dev/sda /dev/sdd`

```
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 0773fa22:7212c43a:5ce8bee0:6669d442
           Name : server:0
  Creation Time : Sat Sep 15 07:48:01 2018
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813529600 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9acb67e2:e0c688d0:092e1803:d422b511

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan  8 00:16:14 2019
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : bf1d961a - correct
         Events : 32944

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

#### Output: `mdadm -D /dev/md0`

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : server:0
              UUID : 0773fa22:7212c43a:5ce8bee0:6669d442
            Events : 32944

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

---

Trying to assemble the array using `mdadm --assemble` fails with,

```
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdd has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like there's a guid partition table on sda and sdd?  Did you make the array out of the partitions sda1 and sdd1, etc.?  If so, you'll want to assemble the array with the partitions, not with the underlying devices.

Comment: @MikeAndrews no, I am fairly certain that I used the raw block devices themselves. Actually all six drives has a GPT on them with with the words "Micsrosoft reserved" when I look at the raw bytes on the drives. I think actually it's leftover data from previous use. The only difference I see is that sdd and sdf both have just zeros where the other ones have their RAID superblock. So the superblock does actually seem to just be done, somehow. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so through inspections I have come to the conclusion that the reason that it was detected as a "Microsoft reserved" partition is because those two drives somehow didn't in fact have their mdadm superblock anymore. The output of `xxd -s 0x1000 -l 0x200 /dev/sdd` confirmed that there was just zeroes on both d and f. <s>No idea how this happened</s>. It seems like this happens every time I end up booting into Windows. I have now removed any old partition tables that existed on the drives. This should hopefully stop Windows from overwriting the superblocks.

Mostly following [RAID Recovery](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery)

I eventually ended up recreating the array. Running the following command `mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=6 /dev/md0 /dev/sda missing /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf` worked and after mounting as read only to check `mount -o ro /dev/md0 /mnt` the data were all there it seems.

Unfortunately this reset the event count among other things meaning that re-adding /dev/sdb didn't work so it's now recreating from scratch.